# how to send laravel reset password email queued

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-queue, laravel-mail

im using laravel 5.4.20 and i want to make reset password emails queued.

i customized reset password email a little (for change subject).

first i created the notification for it :

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class ResetPassword extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
use Queueable;
public $token;

public function __construct($token)
{
    $this->token = $token;
}


public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['mail'];
}



public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject('its sub')
        ->line('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.')
        ->action('Reset Password', url('password/reset', $this->token))
        ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.');
}



public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        //
    ];
}
}
```

and then i used this fucntion in my app/user model

```
use Notifiable;

public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
    // Your your own implementation.
    $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
}
```

the email is correct and it will sent. but now what should i do for make this email queued? thank you

Comment: Take a look at the laravel documentation about Queues - https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues

Comment: @Desh901. fine. but that is just about queues and sending mail handly. thats not about make laravel reset email queued

Comment: You've already set the `ShouldQueue` interface that is everything that Laravel need to detect if the notification has to be queued or not. In order to make it work you should setup your queue and set the `QUEUE_DRIVER` key to `database` in your `.env` file if you're using the database as a queue. You will find all the additional details if your using different services as a queue (e.g. redis etc.)

Comment: Yes i set it up and its database . But its not working. In terminal i use : php artisan queue:listen but nothing happened

Comment: so `QUEUE_DRIVER` is set to `database` ?

Comment: Yes. Its right.

Comment: Where is main reset password mail in laravel 5.4.20?? I think i should Change it

Comment: no body has any idea???